# SQL Server Read and Load Text File using function, Error whilst Opening file

Tags: sql, function

I am using the below function but it is giving me an error 
Error whilst Opening file "C:\MyData\TEST.txt",

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ReadfileAsTable]
(
@Path VARCHAR(1000),
@Filename VARCHAR(100)
)

RETURNS 
@File TABLE
(
[LineNo] int identity(1,1), 
line varchar(8000)) 

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE  @objFileSystem int
        ,@objTextStream int
        ,@objErrorObject int
        ,@strErrorMessage Varchar(1000)
        ,@Command varchar(1000)
        ,@hr int
        ,@String VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@YesOrNo INT

select @strErrorMessage='opening the File System Object'
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OACreate  'Scripting.FileSystemObject' , @objFileSystem OUT


if @hr=0 Select @objErrorObject=@objFileSystem, @strErrorMessage='Opening file "'+@Path+'\'+@Filename+'"',@Command=@Path+'\'+@Filename

if @hr=0 execute @hr = sp_OAMethod @objFileSystem  , 'OpenTextFile'
    , @objTextStream OUT, @Command,1,false,0--for reading, FormatASCII


WHILE @hr=0
    BEGIN
    if @hr=0 Select @objErrorObject=@objTextStream, 
        @strErrorMessage='finding out if there is more to read in "'+@Filename+'"'
    if @hr=0 execute @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @objTextStream, 'AtEndOfStream', @YesOrNo OUTPUT

    IF @YesOrNo<>0  break
    if @hr=0 Select @objErrorObject=@objTextStream, 
        @strErrorMessage='reading from the output file "'+@Filename+'"'
    if @hr=0 execute @hr = sp_OAMethod  @objTextStream, 'Readline', @String OUTPUT
    INSERT INTO @File(line) SELECT @String
    END


if @hr=0 Select @objErrorObject=@objTextStream, 
    @strErrorMessage='closing the output file "'+@Filename+'"'
if @hr=0 execute @hr = sp_OAMethod  @objTextStream, 'Close'


if @hr<>0
    begin
    Declare 
        @Source varchar(255),
        @Description Varchar(255),
        @Helpfile Varchar(255),
        @HelpID int

    EXECUTE sp_OAGetErrorInfo  @objErrorObject, 
        @Source output,@Description output,@Helpfile output,@HelpID output
    Select @strErrorMessage='Error whilst '
            +coalesce(@strErrorMessage,'doing something')
            +', '+coalesce(@Description,'')
    insert into @File(line) select @strErrorMessage
    end
EXECUTE  sp_OADestroy @objTextStream
    -- Fill the table variable with the rows for your result set

    RETURN 
END
```

My effort is to load the data from text file into SQL Server temp table. I can use this temp table for further query based on path,file name passed to this function.

I executed the above using below commands

```
Select line from
 dbo.[ReadfileAsTable]('C:\MyData','TEST.txt')
where line not like'#%' 
--where line doesnt begin with a hash
```

Please advice.

Comment: It is inserting/loading error description as "Error whilst Opening file "C:\MyData\TEST.txt"," in the result set. Whereas the data in the text file is "This is my test data to import"

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here: Does the file really exist on `C:\MyData`? I'm just askin, because the SQL Server at my company has a different `C:\` drive than my working computer... ;)

Comment: I have SQL Server client installed on my PC. I am assuming it should take the local drives only. Yes, the file exists in my local drive. Also, I tried to import the remote shared file giving as ('http://servername:89/Objects/100/','5.txt')  and results are same..The result set is showing Line 1 as 'Error whilst Opening file...). Kindly advice.

Comment: Is the above code working on any other PC... Can anyone test and let me know ?